# Glassfish Netbeans Attaching to localhost "Connection refused"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have no idea why this started happening and because of this I am not sure what to check. Whenever I want to debug some java code now, I get:

> Attaching to localhost:9009 Connection Refused.

It is glassfish and Netbeans. Now this Chrome connector thing has started appearing.  Unfortunately, now it won't stop on any of my breakpoints. Fantastic.

The last thing I was trying to do was move some hibernate config from .hbm.xml to annotations and that ended up being more pain than it was worth.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can debug this? I have another project in Netbeans and that is also suffering from the same problem.  I have tried rebooting and all of the firewalls are off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open up the glassfish admin console in your browser (http://localhost:4848)
2. Click **Configurations -> server-config -> JVM Settings**.
3. Set **Debug Options** to:
   `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009`
4. Ensure **Debug** is checked.
5. Click **Save**.
6. Restart the server.

Try your debugging again.

For some reason, it had unchecked itself.

Comment: After enable the debugging on glashfish server, don't forget to restart the server.